# How to Execute PL/SQL Procedure with Typed Input Param from DBTransactionImpl

Tags: plsql, oracle11g, oracle-adf

Oracle ADF/JDeveloper 11.1.1.7. Oracle DB.

I am trying to call a stored procedure written as:

```
create or replace 
PROCEDURE SP_ADD_AUDIT_COMMENT_BY_RECID (ct_comments IN TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT)
    AS
            MISSING_REQUIRED_INPUT EXCEPTION;
        BEGIN  
            IF 
                (ct_comments.CUSTOM_APP_RECORD_ID  IS NULL) OR
                (ct_comments.CUSTOM_SOURCE  IS NULL) OR
                (ct_comments.UPDATEDBYDISPLAYNAME IS NULL) OR
                (ct_comments.COMMENTDATE IS NULL) OR
                (ct_comments.WFCOMMENT IS NULL)
            THEN
                RAISE MISSING_REQUIRED_INPUT;
            ELSE
                INSERT All
                    INTO AUDIT_RECORD_INSTANCE (CUSTOM_APP_RECORD_ID, CUSTOM_SOURCE, INSTANCEID, COMPOSITEINSTANCEID) VALUES (ct_comments.CUSTOM_APP_RECORD_ID, ct_comments.CUSTOM_SOURCE, ct_comments.INSTANCEID, ct_comments.COMPOSITEINSTANCEID)
                    INTO AUDIT_WFCOMMENTS (CUSTOM_APP_RECORD_ID, CUSTOM_SOURCE, TASKID, UPDATEDBY, UPDATEDBYDISPLAYNAME, COMMENTDATE, WFCOMMENT, SCOPE ) VALUES (ct_comments.CUSTOM_APP_RECORD_ID, ct_comments.CUSTOM_SOURCE, ct_comments.TASKID, ct_comments.UPDATEDBY, ct_comments.UPDATEDBYDISPLAYNAME, ct_comments.COMMENTDATE, ct_comments.WFCOMMENT, ct_comments.SCOPE)
                SELECT * FROM dual;            
            END IF;
            EXCEPTION
                WHEN MISSING_REQUIRED_INPUT THEN
                --DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE ('One or more required input values are missing.');
                raise_application_error (-20001,'One or more required input values are missing.');
        END;
```

This works fine from SQL Worksheet using:

```
DECLARE pComment TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT;
    BEGIN
                    pComment := TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT('123','SOURCE','1','2','3','jSmith','Joe Smith',
                    to_timestamp('06-APR-15 02.25.58.187000000 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'),'TEST COMMENT SP','SCOPE');
                    SCHEMANAME.SP_ADD_AUDIT_COMMENT_BY_RECID(pComment);

           END;
```

In AppModule, a method gets the params and tries to execute the procedure as so:

```
public void insertNewGenericComment(Comments comments){
         String input =
            "pComment := TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT('" + comments.getAssessmentId() + "', '"
            + comments.getCustomSource() + "', '"
            + comments.getInstanceid() + "', '"
            + comments.getTaskId() + "', '"
            + comments.getCompositeInstanceId() + "', '"
            + comments.getUpdatedBy() + "', '"
            + comments.getUpdatedbyDisplayName() + "', to_timestamp('"
            + comments.getCommentDate() + "','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'), '"
            + comments.getComment() + "', '"
            + comments.getScope() + "'); SCHEMANAME.SP_ADD_AUDIT_COMMENT_BY_RECID(pComment);";

        DBTransactionImpl dbti = (DBTransactionImpl)getDBTransaction();
        dbti.executeCommand("DECLARE pComment TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT; begin " + input + " end;");
```

I've tried many variations but why can't I just execute the sql as works in Worksheet?

The JBO error with above is:

```
There was an error adding a new comment: oracle.jbo.SQLStmtException: JBO-27121: SQL error during statement execution. Statement: DECLARE pComment TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT; begin pComment := TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT('210', 'AssignCustomTaskflow', 'NA', 'NA', 'NA', 'anonymous', 'anonymous', to_timestamp('16-Jun-15 02.58.20.000000502 PM','DD-MON-RR HH.MI.SS.FF AM'), ' test', 'NA'); SCHEMANAME.SP_ADD_AUDIT_COMMENT_BY_RECID(pComment); end;
```

And the statement from the error message, pasted into SQL Worksheet executes fine as well. Is there no way to pass a verbatim procedure call from ADF?

Comment: So what is the error?  Also, why no bind parameters?  Avoid using literals.

Comment: @OldProgrammer Yes, I could rewrite the procedure and use bind variables to pass in each needed param, that would be easy, but I'm taking the proc as I find it. The jbo error is shown above at the end of my post.

Comment: It just say, "SQL error during statement execution"  What is the ORA-xxxx error?

Comment: @OldProgrammer - msg=ORA-06550: line 1, column 53: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "=" when expecting one of the following: constant exception <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar The symbol "<an identifier>" was substituted for "=" to continue. ORA-06550: line 1, column 263: PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "." when expecting one of the following: constant exception <an identifier> <a double-quoted delimited-identifier> table long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary...

Comment: Then you have a syntax error in your sql string.  Take the value of the complete sql command you are executing, verbatim, and run through another sql tool (sqlplus) and it should show the same error. I don't think you can declare a variable by using DELCARE like that in a statement.

Comment: @OldProgrammer - actually, I outputted what is going into the call and it works fine in a sql tool. The issue seems to be declaring a var PLS-00201: identifier 'TYPE_AUDIT_COMMENT' must be declared ORA-06550: line 1, column 24: PL/SQL: Item ignored ORA-06550: line 1, column 50: PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

Comment: And I think the problem is the way oracle prepares the statement before attempting to execute it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80807/discussion-between-32u-and-oldprogrammer).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example that shows you how to call database procedures with custom types.

[Callable Statements with custom database type adf](http://ramannanda.blogspot.in/2011/11/optimized-update-insert-adf.html)

Comment: This looks like it will work. In the end for the above I recreated the stored procedure to accept typed parameters and that works, but I like that you show the alternative which would have solved my original issue.

Comment: Yes, You cannot directly declare a type like you were doing. JDBC needs to map it to what it can understand, that is why you cannot directly declare types like you were doing.